# displaying jpg to a jPanel

Tags: eclipse, image, jpeg, jlabel, photo

So i am trying to add an image to my program after a button is pressed with a certain value entered into a text field. I want the image to be blank until the button is pressed with the correct value. The only issue i seem to be having is making the photo appear, i know the output should be working. here is the code i have for adding the label.

```
photo = new JLabel();
photo.setBounds(425, 170, 400, 360);
contentPane.add(photo);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("AwsomeSauce.jpg");
```

here is the code for when the value is entered correctly

```
if (error) {
    photo.setIcon(image);
  }
```

now im still pretty new at this so go easy on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple example for you:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label;

    public Frame() {
        getContentPane().add(label = new JLabel(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JButton b = new JButton("show Icon");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                URL resource = getClass().getResource("/res/3_disc.png");
                ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon(resource);
                label.setIcon(ico);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(b,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();    
        frame.setTitle("This is a test");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);    
    }
}
```

"/res/3_disc.png" - is my icon which is placed in my project in res folder.